# In Python remove all stop words bad characters from my pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In Python, I would like to remove all stop words including bad characters in one go from my pandas dataframe.

**This is what I have tried:**

```
stop_words_dataset = pd.read_csv(r'./stop.csv')
stop_words = stop_words_dataset['StopWords'].tolist()

dataframe['description'] = dataframe['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in stop_words]))
```

However, my dataset still contains some characters that are in my stop.csv...

```
stop words = ['OF','FT', '+', '*', '-', '/', ')', '(']
```

For example, `*` and `/` are still in my dataset where it successfully removed `OF` and `FT`, why?

I have also done the same with regex, `[^A-Za-z0-9]+` however, I prefer the stop worklist solution and would like to get this working.

**Concrete example:**

```
stop_words_dataset = pd.read_csv(r'./stops.csv')
stop_words = stop_words_dataset['StopWords'].tolist()
# Remove stop words including bad characters.
dataframe['description'] = dataframe['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in stop_words]))
```

print of stopword list

```
['JUN', 'JUNE', 'JUL', 'JULY', 'AUG', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC', 'FT', '+', '*', '-', '/', ')', '(']
```

Example dataset after cleaning

**Before cleaning**

```
*CHIMNEY CAKE PARAD LONDON
PUMPKIN CAFE DEC
```

**After:**
This contains `*` but `DEC` was removed

```
*CHIMNEY CAKE PARAD LONDON
PUMPKIN CAFE
```

Comment: are the `*` and `/` surrounded by spaces in your original data?

Comment: Please show a concrete example, with example input and result.

Comment: Thank you for the responce. @9769953 added a better example

Comment: @Ben.T No white space

Comment: @MarkK then that is the problem, because you `split` first the string before checking each item of your original string against your stop word list. as  `*` is never a `item` by itself, it is not removed

Comment: Thank you @Ben.T I now see the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for every letter in the word. That's because you're trying to delete the "/", and maybe it is "inside" a word.

Try this:

```
' '.join([''.join([l for l in item if l not in stop_words]) for item in x.split() if item not in stop_words])
```

Comment: I see, maybe as in my example ` *CHIMNEY` is one word not `* CHIMNEY` so this is the reason.

Comment: Yep, and the code snippet I wrote is checking not only for each word, but also for each letter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also split based on the regular expression `\W+` to split on any non-alphanumeric characters.

```
dataframe['description'] = dataframe['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in re.split(r'\W+', x) if item not in stop_words and item != '']))
```

Output:

```
>>> dataframe
                 description
0  CHIMNEY CAKE PARAD LONDON
1               PUMPKIN CAFE
```